# If something begins one day and then continues the next day, without interruption, what do you call it?

Tags: word-request

If something begins one day and then continues the next day, without interruption, what do you call it? Does it spill or stretch into the next day? I feel I forgot the right word.

Comment: Context please. What are we talking about? A conference, a storm, a road trip, an illness? Was it planned to last more than a day or did something unexpected happen to prolong it? Can you give a specific example?

Comment: @TypeIA I don't see the need to provide context. For example, a battle can last until the following day. So it [does something] into the next day

Comment: The most natural way to say this will depend on the factors I mentioned. Providing context will allow for a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue would be the most common word used in that context.
other possible wordings you may be looking for include...

It extended into the next day.

it lasted until the next day.

It persisted into the next day.

Comment: "... in that context." What context? The questioner didn't give any. As you point out there are many options, and it's impossible to say which fits best without more details.